# Error 1054, no conoce una columna que no existe

Tags: mysql, datatables

Tengo un problema al hacer las consultas de update en mi bbdd, y no tiene sentido, os dejo una foto del error:

[image: Error 1054]

Como podéis ver, me da el error 1054, no conoce la columna usuario, pero, no hay una columna usuario.

En este create table es mi .sql, para la creación de la tabla:

```
        CREATE TABLE usuario(
        id_usuario INT(4) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        nombre VARCHAR(50), 
        correo VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        contraseña VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        tipo_usuario VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    );
```

-Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Tiene pinta de que sea porque en el where estás poniendo como valor una cadena "2" en lugar de un entero 2. Como no coinciden los tipos, te dice que el campo no existe. Cambia ese set y quita las comillas que rodean el 2

Comment: Con o sin comillas, el mismo error

Comment: Suena a algún `TRIGGER` que está disparando esa tabla. Verifica eso. No quita que respetes los tipos, como te indica @Jakala, si son números no uses comillas. En el mejor de los casos forzarás una conversión de tipos, pero eso no es óptimo.

Comment: Para ver los `TRIGGER` definidos en esa tabla puedes usar esta consulta: **`SHOW TRIGGERS FROM <AQUIELNOMBREDELABASEDEDATOS> WHERE table = 'usuario';`**

Comment: Si es un trigger, pero no tiene sentido, por que no hacía si quiera referencia a esa tabla, muchas gracias Cedano :)

Comment: El mensaje de error en este caso proviene del `TRIGGER`, es decir, dentro de él estás intentando usar un nombre de columna desconocido.  Es cierto que si no te ha ocurrido antes te quedas desconcertado, porque el mensaje de error nunca hace referencia al origen del problema, que no es la consulta `UPDATE` en sí misma, sino el `TRIGGER` que dispara dicha consulta. Me ocurrió algo parecido en el pasado y por eso supe que era problema en un `TRIGGER`.